# What is the event to know focus out from a datagrid cell (column) without using itemRenderer or itemEditor

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

I am using a editable datagrid and want to autosave the edited information in an editable column. Also, since its a simple text editing I don't want to use itemEditor/Component for the same. I was hoping to have a focusOut event but I dont see any focusOut event for datagrid column(even if its editable?). What event should I be using?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post some of your code? I'm not quite understanding how you're editing a column or how you're doing it without using an `itemRenderer` or `itemEditor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using itemRenderer in which I used a text box and handled it with textbox's focusOut property. Still wondering how could I have done it directly from dataGrid's event.